# Is there a difference between calling a PHP-Script via browser or via CLI?

Tags: php, http, webserver, command-line-interface

Me and my roommate are both developing.. I'm testing my scripts via browser.. he calls his scripts via CLI, and he tries to convince me, to do that via CLI, too.. "because it is different" .. I don't see any difference and I think it is illogical..... so beside the http/tcp-overhead.. is there any essential difference between when a script is called via HTTP or via CLI?

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP**

The values can be passed as **GET** or **POST** method which will be available in php global arrays **$_GET** and **$_POST** respectively.

```
http://localhost/project/index.php?id=4
```

**CLI**

Value of ID can be access by `$_GET['id']`
But in **CLI** mode, the values can be passed as arguments which will be available in $argv array.

```
php /var/www/project/index.php 4
```

Value can be accessed by `$argv[1]`

Answer (score 0):

On most environments the cli version is not loading the same php.ini settings. And this is used to avoid **limits** applied in the embedded (mod_php) or daemon (php-fm) version.

In cli mode, for example, you do not need low **memory_limit** and **max_execution_time**.

This is one of the **great advantage** of cli mode for asynchronous tasks (which can be long and memory heavy tasks).

Now, for **testing** an application, if the final application **has to be running** in an http server (mod_php) or in a php daemon (php-fpm), testing the application in cli mode is a **disadvantage**, because your tests won't detect the big problems (like crash on memory limit reached or absence of response in case of max_execution time reached -- or even with any other timeout coming before (in the http server or in the fastcgi protocol)--.